# Help with a min max Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Below is my solution to a Calculus Problem. The problem is that the book gets $(-1,1)$ as one of the critical points. I get $(-1,-1)$ as the third critical point. I agree with the book on the other two points. I would like to know if I am wrong or if the book is wrong.
Thanks
Bob

Problem:

Test the following function for maxima, minima, and saddle points. Find the function values at these points.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) &=& 4xy - x^4 - y^4 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_x(x,y) &=& 4y - 4x^3 \\
f_y(x,y) &=& 4x - 4y^3 \\
f_{xx}(x,y) &=& -12x^2 \\
f_{yy}(x,y) &=& -12y^2 \\
f_{xy}(x,y) &=& 4 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now to solve for the critical points we set $f_x(x,y) = f_y(x,y) = 0$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
4y - 4x^3 &=& 0\\
4x - 4y^3 &=& 0\\
y - x^3 &=& 0\\
x - y^3 &=& 0\\
y &=& x^3 \\
x &=& y^3 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence we have three critical points $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. The value of $f(x,y)$ at these points are $0$, $2$ and $2$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{xx}(0,0) &=& 0 \\
f_{yy}(0,0) &=& 0 \\
f_{xy}(0,0) &=& 4 \\
f_{xx}(0,0) f_{yy}(0,0) - { f_{xy}(0,0) } ^2 &=& 0 - 4^2 = - 16 < 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, I conclude that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point. Now for the point $(1,1)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{xx}(1,1) &=& -12 \\
f_{yy}(1,1) &=& -12 \\
f_{xy}(1,1) &=& 4 \\
f_{xx}(1,1) f_{yy}(1,1) - f_{xy}(1,1)^2 &=& (-12)(-12) - 4^2 = 144 - 16 > 0
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, I conclude that $(1,1)$ is a local maximum. Now for the point $(-1,-1)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{xx}(-1,-1) &=& -12 \\
f_{yy}(-1,-1) &=& -12 \\
f_{xy}(-1,-1) &=& = 4 \\
f_{xx}(-1,-1) f_{yy}(-1,-1) - f_{xy}(-1,-1)^2 &=& (-12)(-12) - 4^2 \\
_{xx}(-1,-1) f_{yy}(-1,-1) - f_{xy}(-1,-1)^2 &=& 144 - 16 > 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, I conclude that $(-1,-1)$ is a local maximum.

Comment: it exist no Minimum, the function tends to $-\infty$

Comment: we get that $$f(x,y)\le 2$$ and the equal sign holds for $x=-1,y=-1$

Comment: and yes for $$x=0,y=0$$ we get a saddle point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $$y=x^3$$

If $x=-1$, then $y=-1$, hence the book is wrong.

You are right that $(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)$ are the critical points.